# Calling a Tensorflow model in C++: "output depth must be evenly divisible by number of groups"

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm using [CppFlow](https://serizba.github.io/cppflow/index.html) to read and run a saved Tensorflow model in a C++ code. It should read in a jpeg image and a model, run the model on the image and give back an image of the same size and shape, following [this example](https://serizba.github.io/cppflow/examples.html#efficientnet).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "cppflow/ops.h"
#include "cppflow/model.h"


int main() {
    
    auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(std::string(IMAGE_PATH)));
    input = cppflow::cast(input, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
    
    cppflow::model model(std::string(MODEL_PATH));
    
    auto output = model({{"serving_default_input0:0", input}}, {"StatefulPartitionedCall:0"});
    
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
2022-10-13 11:52:16.581298: F ./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:427] Check failed: index >= 0 && index < num_total_dims Invalid index from the dimension: 3, 0, C
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The example I'm following isn't great at explaining *why* it does things, so I already had to add the casting to a float in response to an error when it was not stated that my input had to be a float in the documentation. Since this error talks about incorrect dimensions I tried adding the line

```
input = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
```

from the example but I don't know why I would need to do that and it still has an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  output depth must be evenly divisible by number of groups: 64 vs 3
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/model/relu2/Relu}}]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't know much about machine learning (it isn't my model, I'm just helping run it in C++) so if someone could please explain why you might do the `expand_dims` and what the resulting error means that would be really helpful.

Comment: What's your model? See the [mre].

Comment: I don't have a lot of details about the model. As I said, it isn't my model, I'm just helping someone run their model in C++ instead of in Python. I just want a bit more info on what that error message could be referring to, what the 64 and 3 might be from.

Comment: SO is not for discussions. A question and an answer have to be specific and useful to others. That said, a model contains a computation graph, which contains input and output nodes, where a node is a tensor - multidimensional array.